# Specify parameters Wolfram Alpha

Tags: wolfram-alpha

Hopefully, this kind of question is ok, have seen a couple of other WA-queries that hasn't been downvoted. Apologies if not.

I want to minimize say $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$. Wolfram Alpha gives me an answer for different intervals of $a$ which makes sense. However, Is there a way to explicitly specify $a>0, b>0, c>0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can simply include those constraints: [minimize ax^2+bx+c, a>0, b>0, c>0](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize+ax%5E2%2Bbx%2Bc%2C+a%3E0%2C+b%3E0%2C+c%3E0)

Alternatively, you can complete the square and observe the extreme value occurs when $x=-\frac b{2a}$: [complete the square ax^2+bx+c](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize+ax%5E2%2Bbx%2Bc%2C+a>0%2C+b>0%2C+c>0)